# Kafka timestamp on producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

If no timestamp is provided when creating a `ProducerRecord`, one will be provided for you by the Kafka client library:

> The record also has an associated timestamp. If the user did not provide a timestamp, the producer will stamp the
> record with its current time. The timestamp eventually used by Kafka depends on the timestamp type configured for
> the topic.

However, is this timestamp set *early* i.e., before `sendAsync` even returns, reflecting the local enqueue time of the message, or is it set late, i.e., around when the message has reached the head of the queue and is about to be sent?

That is, does the timestamp include (come before) the queuing time, or not?

Comment: Looking at the code of Java Producer it looks like the later. Its the time when `doSend` is called plus time spent in waiting on metadata. This should simulate the timestamp when its about to be sent. 

Here is the [doc link](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L1033)

Comment: @kaysush That's a forked repo, btw. Code could be slightly different

Comment: @BeeOnRope My bad I didn't realise it was a forked repo. Here is the one from [apache repo](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L1033). The functionality is same.

Answer (score 0):

It should be set when you construct `new ProducerRecord`, not via `send` / `sendAsync`, but it also depends on the broker / topic configuration.

For the broker -

> `log.message.timestamp.type`
> Define whether the timestamp in the message is message create time or log append time. The value should be either `CreateTime` or `LogAppendTime`

> Default - `CreateTime`

This means it would be set by the producer, if not provided.

But if this is LogAppendTime, that timestamp is overriden on server-side, after the record is sent by the producer.

Comment: That's not the case: you can see a constructor [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e28e0bf0f2c21206abccfffb280605dd02404678/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L132) which does not set the timestamp, which calls [this primary constructor](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e28e0bf0f2c21206abccfffb280605dd02404678/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L69-L84) with a null timestamp, and that constructor simply assigns the passed value (`null`, here) to the member. So it lets its value "later, somewhere".

Comment: Sure, but see doc comment https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e28e0bf0f2c21206abccfffb280605dd02404678/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L34 + https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e28e0bf0f2c21206abccfffb280605dd02404678/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L63

Comment: Right, we know the producer (writ large) creates the timestamp by default (i.e., when `CreateTime` is used). The question is _where_ exactly: does it include the time spent in the client-side queue (which can be substantial) or not?